# CentOS Linux Virtual Desktop with Android Studio

Tags: android, linux, centos7, virtualhost, remote-desktop

I am planning to create a Virtual instance ( VM ) of CentOS 7.6 on Digital Ocean. This Virtual Instance of CentOS 7.6 Linux will be created to GUI ( Graphical User interface ) i.e Virtual Desktop which I can access remotely from home. I want to install the Android Studio on it so that I can build, develop the android app remotely on this server. My Local home laptop is prone to get corrupted or mismanaged hence feel that have a remote emulator with Android Studio on Linux Virtual desktop will make more sense to maintain & Manage in the long term. It should be repeatable, maintainable, sustainable for the long term to build apps.
Please advise which will be mostly lightweight, easy to manage such environment. Should I go for Gnome or KDE or anything compatible GUI to Android Studio development & building the android apps?

Comment: welcome , windows is best but as you are using linux i prefer Gnome.

Answer (score 0):

Cent OS's default user interfaces is : GNOME Shell (+bash)

so you don't need install GNOME again.
and KDE is one of the Best user interfaces.

answer is simple : KDE